# What is a good introduction to dynamics of Teichmuller space?

Tags: reference-request, dynamical-systems, teichmueller-theory

I am interested in learning about dynamics in the setting of Teichmuller space. Could you recommend a not very painful introduction to that subject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean translation surfaces, interval exchanges and things alike --- there are several very good reviews by Anton Zorich. You can find them on his webpage.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in dynamics on the Teichmüller space of punctured sphere, you might be interested in the Thurston pullback. You can find an introduction to the dynamical system on rational maps and polynomials in the second book from Hubbard on Teichmüller theory